# How to copy a DynamoDB table with a StringSet to a Redshift cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, data-transform

I have a DynamoDB table that I need to copy over to a Redshift cluster. I'm already aware how to do the copy, and have done so successfully on several other tables.

However, I need to copy a table that has a StringSet field (or an array of strings) which [Redshift doesn't support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html).

Is there a way to do a data transform so that my data will just have delimiters between the strings?

E.g. `["A", "B", "C"] -> "A|B|C"`

Comment: How are you doing the copy at the moment what tools/process??

Comment: @JonScott, I'm using the `copy` command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/RedshiftforDynamoDB.html